# Why is 'las', 'uas', and 'tags_acc' equal to 0 while evaluating using spacy's NER model?

Tags: metrics, spacy, named-entity-recognition

```py
    import spacy
    from spacy.gold import GoldParse
    from spacy.scorer import Scorer
    from spacy.attrs import ENT_IOB, ENT_TYPE
    from spacy.tokens import Span
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
       
    def evaluate(ner_model, examples):
        scorer = Scorer()
        for input_, annot in examples:
            doc_gold_text = ner_model.make_doc(input_)
            gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=annot)
            pred_value = ner_model(input_)
            scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
        return scorer.scores
        
    examples = [
        ('I like London and Berlin. India',   
         [(7, 13, 'GPE'), (18, 24, 'LOC')])]
        
    ner_model = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 'en_core_web_sm'
    results = evaluate(ner_model, examples)
    results
```

The results is:

```
{
    'ents_f': 40.0,
    'ents_p': 33.33333333333333,
    'ents_r': 50.0,
    'las': 0.0,
    'tags_acc': 0.0,
    'token_acc': 100.0,
    'uas': 0.0
}
```

Why `'las'`, `'uas'` and `'tags_acc'` are equal to 0 irrespective of how many sentences are passed through for evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

As you evaluate the model which is train for NER, not on POS tagging or Dependency Parsing which are specified by:
uas, las, tags_acc
which are:
UAS (Unlabelled Attachment Score) and LAS (Labelled Attachment Score) are standard metrics to evaluate dependency parsing. UAS is the proportion of tokens whose head has been correctly assigned, LAS is the proportion of tokens whose head has been correctly assigned with the right dependency label (subject, object, etc).
tags_acc is the POS tagging accuracy.